# Выставить selected в option в теге select исходя из значения переменной

Tags: javascript, select

Доброго времени суток ув. знатоки. Большую часть работы по js по мере возможного выполнил. Не могу побороть один момент - есть тег select, в нем определенное колво option. Есть переменная в которой содержится выбранный ранее option. Как при загрузке страницы заставить выставить селектор на выбранный ранее option.
Вот код

```
for($i = 0; $i < $numb; $i++)
        {
            $spl_video = $movie_links[$i].split('&&');
            $vk = $spl_video[0];
            $name_video = $spl_video[1];
            $lang = $spl_video[2];
            $qual = $spl_video[3];

            $arr_movie_links[$i] = "<div><select id=\"donor\" style=\"width: 300px;\" name=\"name_"+$_xf+"["+$j+"]\"><option value=\"0\">Openload</option><option value=\"1\">Uptostream</option><option value=\"2\">Vidoza</option><option value=\"3\">vidtome</option><option value=\"4\">1fichier</option></select>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input style=\"width: 400px;\" placeholder=\"Link\" type=\"text\" name=\"seria_"+$_xf+"["+$j+"]\" value=\""+$vk+"\" /><br><input style=\"width: 300px;\" placeholder=\"Language\" type=\"text\" name=\"lang_"+$_xf+"["+$j+"]\" value=\""+$lang+"\" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input style=\"width: 400px;\" placeholder=\"Quality\" type=\"text\" name=\"quality_"+$_xf+"["+$j+"]\" value=\""+$qual+"\" />&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class=\"remove_field btn btn-red\" style=\"background-color:red;\">X</span></div><br>";

            $j++;
        }
```

в переменной $name_video содержится выбранное ранее значение

Answer (score 0):

Записать переменную с выбранным значением в `localStorage` и затем ставить `value` при загрузке страницы.

Comment: не вариант. использоваться будет при редактировании новости на сайте. в редактирование могут зайти как через год, так и с другого аккаунта, с другого айпи и компа. Будь то пхп я бы без проблем нашел бы решение, но нужно сугубо на js реализовать

Comment: Ну, тогда у Вашей проблемы нет решения т.к. только в базу писать остаётся.